# Convertir fechas en Rstudio a dias del año

Tags: r, date, conversión-de-tipos

Me gustaría saber como puedo convertir una fecha con formato "2016-06-15" al número del año concreto que le corresponde entre 0 y 365/366 con el programa R studio.

Muchas gracias,

Marta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En R el primer valor sería el 1, no en 0, por lo que la serie empezaría en 1 siendo este el 1 de enero.

```
fecha <- as.Date("2016-06-15")
dia <- strftime(fecha, format = "%j")
as.numeric(dia)
```

Espero que esto sea lo que buscas!

Comment: Eso es, muchisímas gracias!!!